# Understanding separation Axioms in Topology

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

**Weak separation Axioms** $(T_0\text{ or Kolmogorov},T_1\text{ or Frechet},T_2\text{ or Hausdorff})$ codify how a topology can distinguish between points in the underlying set, or in the other words how well it can separate points with open sets. They are really intuitive as they show *how sequence convergence*.

But I couldn't see how **Strong separation Axioms** $(T_3\text{ or regular }T_1,T_4\text{ or normal }T_1)$ are stronger than **Weak separation Axioms**. I failed to make an intuition like weak separation Axioms does with sequence convergence.

I see there are different definition for $T_3$ and $T_4$, hence mentioning them below what I am following now:

---

- A topology space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be $T_1$ if for any pair of distinct points $x,y\in X$, there exist open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U$ contain $x$ but not $y$, and $V$ contain $y$ but not $x$.
- A topology space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be **regular** if for any $x\in X$ and any closed set $C$ not containing $x$, there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x\in U$ and $C\subseteq V$.
- A topology space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be $T_3$ if it is both $T_1$ and regular.
- A topology space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be **normal** if for any two disjoint, nonempty, closed subsets $C,D\subseteq X$, there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ containing $C$ and $D$, respectively.
- A topology space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be $T_4$ if it is both $T_1$ and normal.

---

I read all of those in fact that course by my own, maybe that's why I couldn't connect them. It will be great help if someone help me to understand/build an intuition on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one key point is to keep in mind how $T_1$ links **points** and **closed sets**: the $T_1$ axiom is equivalent to "all singletons are closed." With this in mind, we can think of **strong separation axioms as being the "set-ified" versions of weak separation axioms** - *if* we assume $T_1$-ness as well. For example, normality basically *is* Hausdorffness if we replace "(distinct) points" with "(disjoint) closed sets," and regularity is a sort of halfway-point between Hausdorffness and normality (we only "set-ify" halfway).

---

For example, to see that $T_4$ implies $T_2$ (= Hausdorff), given distinct points $x,y$ in a $T_1$ normal space (= $T_4$ space), by $T_1$-ness we know that $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ are disjoint nonempty *closed* sets so by normality we can find disjoint open $U\ni x, V\ni y$ - and this gives the Hausdorff condition.

The proof that $T_3$ implies $T_2$ is basically the same, except we only "set-ify" *one* of the points: given distinct points $x,y$ in a $T_1$ space regular space, by $T_1$-ness we get that $\{y\}$ is a nonempty *closed* set not containing $x$ so by regularity we get disjoint opens $U\ni x, V\ni y$ (the latter since $V\supseteq \{y\}$ is equivalent to $V\ni y$).

---

Of course this analogy breaks down if we don't assume $T_1$. For example, the Sierpinski space is normal but neither $T_1$ nor regular.

Comment: **Strong separation axioms as being the "satisfied" versions of weak separation axioms** Aha, nice link @Noah Schweber. Thanks for your response

Comment: @falamiw Incidentally, it might help to motivate regularity by noting its importance in metrization theory - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrizable_space).

Comment: One question, did you mean satisfied by **set-ified** or **set-ify**?

Comment: @falamiw No, I wrote what I meant. The "---ify" or "---ified" construction basically means "turned in to" or "made in terms of" (see e.g. [categorification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorification)). Here I'm talking about taking notions which were made in terms of *points* and rethinking them in terms of *sets*.

Comment: I see, I wasn't awarded by those term, thanks for introducing them. And I see the Wikipedia link but to be honest I didn't understand properly what they said in [Metrization_theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrizable_space#Metrization_theorems) section. Could you tell me what you mean by **it might help to motivate regularity by noting its importance in metrization theory** in your comment? I will give it a look again, but for now could you tell the long story in short? @Noah Schweber

Comment: @falamiw I just meant that regularity is part of the answer to the question, "When is a topological space metrizable?" I think that *question* is particularly natural, even if regularity itself is a bit weird, so it may help to motivate regularity by first coming to care about metrizability.

Comment: It's a little convoluted.   I used to think $T_n\implies T_m $ for $n\gt m$, but upon closer inspection that is false.  

It would have simplified things.  Oh well.   I like this answer though.

Comment: @ChrisCuster I think they do, since $T_1$-ness is folded into the higher $T_n$s. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I probably just got confused when reading about it.

Comment: @ChrisCuster: There are two different conventions. One of them uses the $T_k$ notations as they were intended to be used, i.e., as a genuine hierarchy, so that $T_n\to T_m$ whenever $n\ge m$. Under this convention *regular*, *completely regular*, *normal*, etc. do not imply $T_1$. The other conventional unaccountably reverses this usage; unfortunately, it is common enough that one must be aware of both conventions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You're right, I should have specified that I was following wikipedia here.